# How to find any Id from list in another list

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a objects stored in MongoDB; each object has a list of `TeamIds`. In my function (see below), I want to pass in a list of `teamIds`. If any of the `teamIds` in the list are found in the `TeamIds` on the database object, I want to return that object.

For example, in the DB I have an object with a list of TeamIds as follows:

```
TeamIds: [1213, 1280]
```

So in my function, I will pass in the `teamIds` list `[1213,1215]`. Since the `teamIds` list contains `1213`, I want to return the database object above. Basically, I need to do an intersection and find out if both arrays have any of the same items. If they do, I want to return the database object. I am just not sure how to do it. Here is my code:

```
    public async Task<List<MyTeamObject>> FindTeamItems(List<int> teamIds)
    {
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<MyTeamObject>(collectionName);
        var filter = Builders<MyTeamObject>.Filter.In(x => x.TeamIds, teamIds);

        var result = await collection.FindAsync<MyTeamObject>(filter);
        var list = result.ToList();

        return list;
    }
```

The code above does not work, of course. The `.In` does not allow me to pass an array into the delegate.

How can I achieve the desired result which I have described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching through the MongoDB docs and I happened to find the answer:

[MongoDB C# 2.5 Driver - AnyIn Filter](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_AnyIn__1.htm)

```
public async Task<List<MyTeamObject>> FindTeamItems(List<int> teamIds)
{
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<MyTeamObject>(collectionName);
    var filter = Builders<MyTeamObject>.Filter.AnyIn(x => x.TeamIds, teamIds);

    var result = await collection.FindAsync<MyTeamObject>(filter);
    var list = result.ToList();

    return list;
}
```